# Simplifying Click Function on Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wrote some code (with a lot of Googling and searching) that, on click of a button, opens a lightbox, toggles some classes and loads some HTML into that lightbox through AJAX. I have 4 buttons, and instead of writing the same code 4 times, I'd like to create a variable that gets the ID of each button, stores the ID, and then loads in the corresponding HTML doc. I have an idea, but I just need some guidance. Example of two buttons:

```
        $("#jaxx").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
            $.ajax({
                context: $('#lightbox-holder'),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : "html",
                url : "/template/jaxx-lightbox.html",
                success : function(results) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#lightbox-holder').html(results);
                        $('section#lightbox').addClass("open");
                    },100);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('a.xbutton').addClass("open");
                    },300);
                }
            });     
        });

        $("#anisha").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
            $.ajax({
                context: $('#lightbox-holder'),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : "html",
                url : "/template/anisha-lightbox.html",
                success : function(results) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#lightbox-holder').html(results);
                        $('section#lightbox').addClass("open");
                    },100);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('a.xbutton').addClass("open");
                    },300);
                }
            });     
        });
```

By the way, these are cats, not strippers.

Comment: FWIW, code review requests generally belong on the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your buttons a class in addition to the ID, you can easily target all of them

```
<button class="cat" id="jaxx">Jaxx</button>
<button class="cat" id="anisha">Anisha</button>
```

And then just use the ID in the URL like this

```
$(".cat").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = this.id

    $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        url: "/template/"+ id +"-lightbox.html",
        success: function(results) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#lightbox-holder').html(results);
                $('#lightbox').addClass("open");
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.xbutton').addClass("open");
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works exactly how I wanted it to with about 60 less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

To convert what you have into a function, simply replace each instance of a name with a variable, like so:

```
function setup(name) {
    $("#" + name).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
        $.ajax({
            context: $('#lightbox-holder'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/template/" + name + "-lightbox.html",
            success: function(results) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#lightbox-holder').html(results);
                    $('section#lightbox').addClass("open");
                }, 100);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('a.xbutton').addClass("open");
                }, 300);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Can be called like so:

```
setup("jaxx");
setup("anisha");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // add class="catbutton" to buttons; you can rename the class
   $(".catbutton").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
       var name = $(this).attr("id");
       $.ajax({
            context: $('#lightbox-holder'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "html",
            url : "/template/"+name+"-lightbox.html",
            success : function(results) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#lightbox-holder').html(results);
                    $('section#lightbox').addClass("open");
                },100);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('a.xbutton').addClass("open");
                },300);
            }
        });     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you need **to write a reusable code or code in a generic fashion for binding events to elements `class` is the best choice**.

Give a class name to all your buttons. Say `lightBox-toggle`. Then using this class bind the event. When you use class selectors, Jquery will select all the elements with the specific class and bind the mentioned event to all of them. So your code would be something like below..

```
$(".lightbox-toggle").on('click',function(e){
        //.... your existing stuff

        $.ajax({
            //.... your existing stuff
            url : "/template/"+$(this).attr('id') +"-lightbox.html",
            //...yourexisting stuff
        });     
    });
```

I have just highlighted the required changes to your existing code, So that its more clear than way. Let me know if this helps

Also note, I have used `.on()` to bind the events, I personally prefer using `on()` because it allows us to bind multiple events at the same time (if required) for Eg: `on('click mouseover mouseout')` . Also removing the events binded by using `on()` can be easily removed using `off()` more details are here [**.on() API Document**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)